# what could cause tables created in Django via models and migrations not to be queryable via PgAdmin

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, relational-database

In my Django app I created models and ran migrations to create tables in my database which I have properly configured in my settings.py file. The tables are created in my database and can be queried using query manager, but I want to use raw SQL but when I do I get the "relation doesn't exist" error including when I query these tables in PgAdmin. All relations created via models are not queryable via regular SQL. What could be the cause of this.

Models.py

```
class Projects(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
No_of_Projects = models.IntegerField()
Spotify = models.BooleanField()
Soundcloud = models.BooleanField()
Apple_music = models.BooleanField()
Youtube_music = models.BooleanField()
Deezer = models.BooleanField()
Tidal = models.BooleanField()
Pandora = models.BooleanField()
Amazon_music = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.Artist
```

migrations.py

```
    migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Projects',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('Artist', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('No_of_Projects', models.IntegerField(default=1)),
                ('Spotify', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Soundcloud', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Apple_music', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Youtube_music', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Deezer', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Tidal', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Pandora', models.BooleanField()),
                ('Amazon_music', models.BooleanField()),
            ],
        ),
```

This model created the relation Machine_projects. which I reference in my views and try to query.

views.py

```
def test2(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if user.is_authenticated:
        print(user)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM auth_user WHERE username = %s", [user.username])
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            print(row[0])
            cursor.execute("SELECT no_of_projects FROM Machine_projects WHERE First_Name = %s", [row[0]]) 
            row2 = cursor.fetchone()
            pro = Projects.objects.get(pk=2)
            print(pro, row2[0])
            all_tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
            print(all_tables)

            
        return redirect('register2')
    else:
        return render(request, 'test2.html')
```

this is the error I get.

error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "machine_projects" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT no_of_projects FROM Machine_projects WHERE First_Name...type here
```

I've deleted the tables by running `py manage.py migrate zero` and redoing the migrations. Only for the same thing to happen.

Comment: You are creating the tables with mixed-case names by quoting them at creation and then not quoting them when you try to access them. This means they get folded to lower-case. If this is confusing, perhaps skim the PostgreSQL manuals or an introductory book

Comment: "mixed-cased names by quoting them at creation". Does this mean that migrations quotes my tables when I create them? because I didn't do that? whether I'm using lower cases the error is always there.

Comment: Something is quoting them - read the docs on your python library to check

Comment: Please update the post with the relevant portions of the model and migration code. Queries and exception messages without such context limits the abilty of others to offer specific suggestions.

Comment: Advice: Never use UPPERcase in the object names. Never. So don't use camel case, but always snake case.

Comment: The identifier, `Machine_projects`, is handled as if it were `machine_projects`. Enclosing it in double quotes as `"Machine_projects"` should address the reported problem; however, as @FrankHeikens said, "**don't use UPPER case in the object names**" that map to database objects.

Comment: @JohnH it worked thanks. Out of curiosity is it the UPPER case that is requiring the double quotes or is it a convention of Django?

Comment: You need double quotes " because of PostgreSQL. Avoid UPPER case like the plague, use snake_case. In Oracle you have the same, but then for "lower case"...